# Dividing 45 plus x

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

Two fishermen were fishing. The first fisherman caught 18 fish, and the second 27 (all fish
are the same size). When they had fried all 45 fish, a stranger joined them and all the fish were
divided equally into three parts. The stranger paid the fishermen \$90 for one equal share. How
should the fishermen divide these \$90 among themselves so that the division is fair?
I think this is a ' trick question ' since \$90 was given as a fair share it means 90 IS the fair share  ( Fishermen )

Comment: Don't know why it would be a trick question.  Hint: how many fish did each eat?  If each fisherman ate from his own catch, how many did the stranger get from the first fisherman and how many from the second?  So, how should the \$90 be divided?

Comment: BTW in MathJax, \$ will enter math mode.  If you actually want a dollar sign you have to type \\$ instead of \$.

Comment: Thank u David I don't ask questions on here often as far as the mathjax.

Comment: Are we looking at all x that ( 45+x)/3 is integer?

Comment: I think the problem is saying that the stranger caught no fish.

Comment: I still don't get it ..I've attempted to solve it ..can u please ' enlighten ' me my friend ? The night is getting long and this problem been bugging me for about a half hour lol

Comment: Unless  , the first dude gets $36 ( 18/45 of the 90) the second gets (25/45) of it

Comment: Is it six dollars a fish ?

Comment: The stranger receives $15$ fishes, and paid $\$90$ for this. So the unit-price of each fish is $\$6$. Fisherman n°1 caught 18 fishes, he eats 15 fishes, and gave 3 to the stranger. 3 fishes, with unit price $\$6$, it means that he should receive $3 \times \$6 =\$18$ for this ; And fisherman n°2 caught $27$ fishes ; he eats $15$ and gave the remaining $12$ to the stranger ; he should receive $12 \times \$6= \$72$.  $\$18+\$72=\$90$, we are ok.

Comment: 36 and 54 is my final answer

Comment: @Randin is your final answer, the answer provided by a third party?

Comment: No why ? I can't think of it on my own any other way but am seeking corroboration with my answer

Answer (score 2):

I do not agree with either answer posted.

Forget about the fish being fried, mixed together so that they are indistinguishable, and then eaten. !

Instead think that the first and second fisherman sold $15$ fish to the stranger after reserving $15$ each for themselves.

Fisherman $1$ must have sold $18-15 = 3$ fish,
and fisherman $2$ must have sold $27-15= 12$ fish,

and @ $\large\frac{90}{15} = 6$\$ per fish,
fisherman $1$ should get $18$ \$,
and fisherman $2$ should get $72$ \$

It is a "trick" question only in the sense that one is likely to wrongly divide the money between them in the proportion of fish caught.

Comment: Hmmm... not incorrect but just like other answers here, one has to assume something. I assumed that they are mixed and then partition $15$, you assumed they did not partition randomly. Neither have what we assumed is in the question. Perhaps there is no other way to solve with just the given information.

Comment: Additionally, the fish were fried, it is stated in the question.

Comment: @Dstarred: As I said, it is immaterial whether the fish were fried or not. Fisherman $1$ amd $2$ *can give fish to the stranger only from the surplus remaining with each after they take 6 each.*  This is not an **assumption** but an inevitability.

Comment: Not really, hundreds of different permutations possible. When they fried the fish they could have mixed it. After all they were split **after** being fried... The question did not say they reserved 15 for themselves first. How do you know in what way they were split? Were you there when it happened? You are only looking at one permutation, which is quite the opposite of inevitable.

Comment: @Dstarred: You are not understanding the crux of the matter. If you employed two apple pickers who were'nt given food, but allowed to eat apples, would you pay them on the apples they **gave** to you or what they actually **collected** (which you would not even know, since you wouldn't know how many they ate)

Comment: But the matter of fact is the fishermen got $15$ fish each as the fish were equally divided no matter what, **in the end**. It was not stated that it was reserved. If you divide a box of pizza randomly and equally among 3 people, each person still gets a slice of the pizza, as do the fishermen (15 fish). By stating they needed to reserve is subjective and assumed. As for the apple matter, it is stated that stranger gave $\$90$ regardless of whose fish they were to both fishermen combined (a.k.a for the $15$ fish he got).

Comment: @Dstarred: You talk somewhere about permutations. We aren't concerned about who ate which fish, only about **numbers** of fish. Consider the extreme scenario where first fisherman caught $15$ fish, second fisherman caught $30$, and after frying, all three (including stranger) ate $15$ fish each, would you give fisherman $1$ $30$\$ ?

Comment: Why is it a "trick question" just because the fishermen might have solved it incorrectly???

Comment: @David: It isn't, that's why I wrote "trick", considering school assignment, maybe. See how much trouble I had in convincing what the correct answer should be.

Comment: @trueblueanil ... *is* in italics makes it look as if you are saying it *is* a trick question.

Comment: @David: You are right, I will change that

Comment: @trueblueanil Yes, because it is a $2 : 1$ ratio now. So fisherman $1$, gets $\$30$.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is 90$ and a trick question . If anyone provides a number theoretical solution I would be very grateful . If it's not 90 then we have (45 + x )/3 =9o where x is fish caught by stranger .

Comment: The stranger does not catch any fish !

Answer (score 0):

The "trick" is not actually a trick, but realising that no matter what subset of the $45$ fish are given to the stranger, the amount of money will be split out at ratio of $27 : 18 \to 3 : 2$, (due to the pre-factor of each fish is same.)

This question targets the relevance of total work contributed and its subsequent income, not the splitting of the fish from each fishermen. Since fisherman 2 **did more work** than fisherman 1, he will get paid more.

Another factor that plays well into this is that the fish are **fried and mixed together**, then split equally, hence out the $15$ fish given to the stranger, $9$ fish came from fisherman $2$ and $6$ fish came from fisherman $1$. See that fisherman $2$ has contributed more fish in the equal splitting than fisherman $1$ (both before splitting and thus after).

Hence, fisherman $2$ is paid $\$54$ and fisherman $1$ is paid $\$36$.

Comment: 54 + 36 is not correct.

Comment: @Lourrran kindly enlighten me with your counter argument, please.

Comment: Each one eats 15 fishes. Fisher n°1 gives 3 fishes to the 'bank', and n°2 gives 12 fishes.  For 3+12 fishes, stranger pays \$ 90, so \$ 6 for each fish.

Comment: But $12 : 3 ≠ 3 : 2$. How did you arrive at $12 : 3$ ratio?

Comment: Imagine another problem, more simple. Fisher n°1 takes 15 fishes, and n°2 takes 30 fishes. You consider that fisher n°1 will receive some money (\$ 30); I consider that fisher n°1 is autonomous (same 15 fishes he got and he eats), and stranger paid \$ 90 to fisher n°2.

Comment: The question does not concern individual fish count, rather as a holistic income proportional to work done. This is because the $45$ fish were split but no information given on which fisherman contributed how many to each $15$ part. Hence, out of the $15$ fish, we look towards work contributed to pay the fishermen accordingly (which is a $3 : 2$ ratio).

Comment: @Lourrran By stating _"fisher n°1 is autonomous (same 15 fishes he got and he eats), and stranger paid $ 90 to fisher n°2"_  additional arguments are being enforced, that were never stated in the question.